# tmap coming up with blank map with one variable (but values are there)

Tags: r, r-sf, tmap

I have two numeric variables I'm using to create two thematic maps using the tmap package. The same code works for one of the variables, but creates a blank map for the other. I created a small subset of the data to reproduce the error, here the last category still has some colour, but the rest are blank. In the full data set all categories are blank.

I really have no idea what is happening, the two variables are same class/type, and I get a proper plot using plot(), so I cannot think what's wrong! Any tips would be much appreciated!

Here is the code I tried:

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)


df <- dget("https://www.dropbox.com/s/8yap9bdknyvelwq/tmap_df.txt?dl=1") 

#works:
tm_shape(df) + 
  tm_fill("v1", style = "quantile", title = "Change in V1", border.alpha = 0, palette = "-RdBu", midpoint = 0)

#doesn't work:
tm_shape(df) + 
  tm_fill("v2", title = "Change in V2",  style = "quantile", border.alpha = 0, palette = "-RdBu", midpoint = 0)

#the two variables are the same class/type
class(df$v1) == class(df$v2)
typeof(df$v1) == typeof(df$v2)

#if I use plot(), it works
plot(df[,1])
plot(df[,2])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't read the data it gives me an error `Error in parse(file = file, keep.source = keep.source) :unexpected $end`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue is related to the scale fo your variables.

try:

```
summary(df$v1)
summary(df$v2)
```

and you will notice that a small share of your data has large values

```
dim(df[df$v2>0,])
dim(df[df$v2>10000,])
```

A solution might be manually set the breaks. Something like this:

```
tm_shape(df) + 
tm_fill("v2", title = "Change in V2",  
        breaks = c(-1000, -500, 0, 500, 1000, 10000, 30000), 
        border.alpha = 0, palette = "-RdBu")
```

That will produce:

[image]

You can set your breaks as you see fit. 
Change the pallete (or manually creating a new pallete) can improve the map.

```
tm_shape(df) + 
  tm_fill("v2", title = "Change in V2",  
          breaks = c(-1000, -500, 0, 500, 1000, 10000, 30000), 
          border.alpha = 0, palette = "-Greens")
```

[image]

```
tm_shape(df) + 
  tm_fill("v2", title = "Change in V2",  
          breaks = c(-1000, -500, 0, 500, 1000, 10000, 30000), 
          border.alpha = 0, palette = "PuBuGn")
```

[image]

Moreover, you can specify the labels trhough the **labels** argument.

Hope it helps to shed light on you issue.